# ¿Como sanitizar/limpiar caracteres y entidades HTML en PHP?

Tags: php, html

Me gustaría sanitizar el input del usuario en un formulario con PHP para evitar que el usuario, por ejemplo intente escribir `<`, `>` ya que el input es lo que se escribe en el documento HTML...

El usuario , en el campo debe escribir la URL (enlace) que desea acortar, así que necesito el código para que el POST elimine caracteres como `<`, o que no son de una URL.

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en Español. Por favor toma el **[recorrido del sitio](http://es.stackoverflow.com/tour)** y lee 
**[cómo crear una buena pregunta](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)**. Por favor **[edit] tu pregunta** incluyendo el código que uses para lograr lo que describes en tu pregunta.

Answer (score 3):

Puedes usar htmlspecialchars()
htmlspecialchars — Convierte caracteres especiales en entidades HTML

```
<?php
$nuevo = htmlspecialchars("<a href='test'>Test</a>", ENT_QUOTES);
echo $nuevo; // &lt;a href=&#039;test&#039;&gt;Test&lt;/a&gt;
?>
```

Me imagino que tambien te puede servir strip_tags().
strip_tags — Retira las etiquetas HTML y PHP de un string

```
<?php
$text = '<p>Test paragraph.</p><!-- Comment --> <a href="#fragment">Other     text</a>';
echo strip_tags($text);
echo "\n";

// Permite <p> y <a>
echo strip_tags($text, '<p><a>');
?>
```

El resultado del ejemplo sería:

```
Test paragraph. Other text
<p>Test paragraph.</p> <a href="#fragment">Other text</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Con javascript, solo es tener los codigos que no queres incluir y validarlos. Ej:

```
 <script>
 function noCharacter(evt) {
 var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : event.keyCode
 if (charCode > 58 && charCode < 65)
    {
        alert('Caractér no valido');
    }
 return true;
 }
 </script>
 <body>
 <input type="text" id="a" name="a" onkeypress="noCharacter(event);" />
 </body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Si quieres quitar los caracteres (< >) puedes hacerlo usando ***str_replace***

[Documentación oficial](http://php.net/manual/es/function.str-replace.php)

Ej:

```
 $url = $_POST['url'];
 $search = array("<",">");
 $url = str_replace($search,"", $url);
```

Php pose una función para filtra las variables, la cual filtra también el URL te  dejo el ejemplo:

[Documentación Oficial](http://php.net/manual/es/function.filter-var.php)

```
$url = $_POST['url'];    
$url = filter_var($url, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL);
```

Answer (score 0):

El filtro `FILTER_SANITIZE_URL` elimina todos los caracteres de una `url` que son ilegales de una cadena.

Este filtro *permite* todas las **letras**, los **dígitos** y  `$ -_. +! * '(), {} | \\ ^ ~ []` `"> <#%; /?: @ & =`

*Ejemplo:*

```
//Obtenemos URL mediante POST.
$url = $_POST['url'];

//Salida url.
var_dump(filter_var($url, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));
```

[Manual PHP - filter_input()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-input.php)
[w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/php/filter_sanitize_url.asp)

Otra opción seria usar la función `filter_var`, Filtra una variable con el filtro que se indique.

```
<?php
//Obtenemos URL mediante POST.
$url = $_POST['url']; 

//Comprobamos validez URL.
if (!filter_var($url, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL) === false) {
    echo("$url es una URL valido");
} else {
    echo("$url no es una URL valido");
}
?>
```

[Manual - PHP filter_var()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php)